# how to catch multiple ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My button is dynamic. So, It has multiple ids say view-123, view-324, view-423 etc. On button click I am calling a `jQuery` file having:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('tr[id^view-]').click(function() {
            alert(this.id)
        });
    });
```

To catch the `id`, But it is not working?

```
 $('.view').click(function() {
        alert(this.id)
   });
```

This is returning nothing.
html is:

```
{% for item in users %}

          <tr class="row">
            <td class="number">{% if item.phone_number %}{{ item.phone_number }}{% else %}-{% endif %}</td>

            <td><input type="submit" class="view" name="view-{{ item.phone_number }}" value="View"></td>

          </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you copy & paste some HTML?

Comment: I updated my question with some html. Hope useful.

Answer (score 11):

Try using `^=` rather than just `^`:

```
 $('tr[id^="view-"]')
```

Also, this would be nicer if you used a class for all the applicable elements.

Comment: +1 for recommending classes, using a class for the elements would make the selector run faster.

Comment: @user You have replace the ID attribute with a class attribute. It shouldn't surprise you that nothing is appearing in the alert!  You probably want something like `<tr class="row" id="{{item.id}}">`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match multiple elements at once, you're better off using a class rather than multiple IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add class to button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.class').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

i think this is easy way .. Thanks